# if the custom tableviewCell has "TextField", how it easy to map to modal property？

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

> Situation:

if there has a UITableview have 10 cell on it,

there have "UILabel + UITextField" in each cell, also have 10 modal property corresponding to each cell, Each cell is get value in different property in the modal, also user change the value in the UITextField on the cell, also update the corresponding modal properTY value

```
like : 
value in modal.name is corresponding "section:1 row:1" cell
value in modal.age is corresponding "section:1 row:2" cell
....
```

> question:

is there have any easy way handle this situation?
cause i dont't like to set the value one by one in method "**cellForRowAtIndexPath**"

```
like:
if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1) {
       cell.textFiled = modal.name;
}
```

also the textField value change in cell"section:1 row:1", how to update the "modal.name" easily?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add two methods in custom cell class. 
One is: `-(void)configureCellWithModel` for display data.
Another is: `-(void)updateCellWothModel` for update data.

Put these methods in the custom cell class.

Comment: could you please tell more about this? i still could not clear about this?

Comment: Sorry, I have misunderstood of your question. If you have difference cells in different indexpaths. You must assign the specific index and update the modal. But you can remove the  code in method "cellForRowAtIndexPath" to the custom cell class for make the code clean to read and maintain.